# Combine two ModelForm fields in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a model with a boolean field and a foreign key

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    is_anonymous = BooleanField(default=False)
    page = ForeignKey(ModelB, null=True)
```

I want to combine these two fields in a select field.

It should have an option `<option value="anonymous">Anonymous</option>` and an option for each object in `ModelB`.

So if a page is selected in the `<select>` the field `is_anonymous` should be false and if anonymous is selected the field `page` should be null and `is_anonymous` should be true.

I think I will have to add the queryset `ModelB.objects.all()` to the choice list in

```
self.fields['field_name'].widget = forms.Select(choices=[(False, "Not anonymous"), (True, "Anonymous"),])
```

but it will save the result to the field `field_name` which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to combine fields here. You can just set the empty_value for the foreign key field to 'anonymous', and deal with it in the clean method.

```
class ModelAForm(forms.ModelForm):
    page = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ModelB.objects.all(), empty_value="Anonymous")

    class Meta:
        model = ModelB

    def clean(self):
        if not self.cleaned_data['page']:
            self.cleaned_data['anonymous'] = True
```

Comment: It's a good solution. The problem is that I need another choice. The options will be `["Anonymous", "My username", (model b objects)`. Only if `anonymous` is selected the field `anonymous` should be true. Can it be done with a `ModelChoiceField`?